# How to deny collection insert/update in the server side

Tags: mongodb, security, meteor, collections

I have a `Meteor` app (**A**) that connects to some production remote collections (which is used by another app **B**) and I just want **A** to read data from B's collections and **not modify B's collections data** (even if the modification takes place in the server-side of **B**).
How can I do that inside of **A** ?

Comment: Could you not just have typed ["mongodb security"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mongodb+security) into search engine? You could have. And then you could have realized that "database administration" is "off topic" for a programming site. You can ask on [dba.stackexchange,com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) where there are probably answers, but actually reading the documentation "should" solve this for you. Also please don't include tag names as part of question titles. The tags on your question get included as meta data for search engines anyway.

Comment: Oh look an answer on the dba site: [Mongodb restrict access on collections level](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53953/mongodb-restrict-access-on-collections-level) which of course does little more than point to the documentation. Example usage is there.

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn, thanks for the suggestions about tag names. About the question, there's two things: 1. I'm asking about a Meteor-specific solution and 2. I want to know how to do that inside of app A because I don't want to mess up app B's mongo configuration.

Comment: Well writing "code" to authorize access to functions ( or loading a plugin for your app ) is an option, but it would not seem "suited" to the case of "block **A** from **B** etc". If you took a moment to actually read the manual I think you'll find that it really does exactly what you are asking, just by setting up a different user for each "App". The part I now realize you still probably are not getting is that in the "real world" your meteor app is "just code". The actual MongoDB part will be connecting to an "external" server, and not the per instance as used in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have total control of what your Meteor app Server code can do in the database.

To make sure your app A Server code cannot write to DB, simply **never** use any collection `insert`, `update` or `upsert` method.

Meteor is special in the fact that it can also allow Client side initiated DB modifications: simply make sure you remove the `insecure` package and **never** use a collection `allow` method in your Server code.

Now the very simple, bullet proof and standard practice solution for your case is simply to create a different database user for your app A, with only read permission, as explained by @NeilLunn. This different DB user credentials are then part of the `MONGO_URL` variable that you pass to your app A, so that is the only mean of connection of your app A to the remote DB that is in common with app B.